# linux cut out the reg expression pattern by sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a text file and I want to remove the strings before the colon.

txt file:

```
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NW-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:05556808    0.916496542
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NW-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:08883127    0.891518088
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NW-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:10537079    0.827900035
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NW-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:12497728    0.90517593
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NW-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:13195463    NA
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NW-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:22240159    0.809459655
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NW-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:27050343    NA
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NY-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:05556808    0.816581048
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NY-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:08883127    0.864387435
jhu-usc.edu_.450.1.lvl-3.TA-LK-A4NY-01A-11D-A34E-05.txt:10537079    0.565236625
```

Desired output:

```
5556808 0.916496542
8883127 0.891518088
10537079    0.827900035
12497728    0.90517593
13195463    NA
22240159    0.809459655
27050343    NA
5556808 0.816581048
8883127 0.864387435
10537079    0.565236625
```

I tried `sed 's/\.[^:]*$//' file` but didn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? See also how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Are your columns tab-separated?

Comment: Your desired output removed leading zero for `05556808` , `08883127`...Is it typo? or you need output like that only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `sed`:

  ```
  sed 's/^[^:]*://' file.txt
  ```
- `grep`:

  ```
  grep -o '[^:]*$' file.txt
  ```
- `awk`:

  ```
  awk -F: '{print $2}' file.txt
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to match up to the last `:` and remove that part:

```
sed 's/^.*://' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/noTy5T)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `.*` - any characters as many as possible (that means up to the last ...)
- `:` - colon.

Comment: I guess that the `^` isn't really doing anything useful here.

Comment: @TomFenech: Just making sure we are at the start (yes, it is not doing much here). I like to keep patterns verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, here ":" is set as delimiter of the fields and NF represents last filed. sub is used to remove leading zero from last field.(As per your desired o/p). However if you do not wish to remove leading zero then just remove `sub(/^0/,"")`  from below command.

```
awk -F: '{$0=$NF;sub(/^0/,"")}1' infile
5556808    0.916496542
8883127    0.891518088
10537079    0.827900035
12497728    0.90517593
13195463    NA
22240159    0.809459655
27050343    NA
5556808    0.816581048
8883127    0.864387435
10537079    0.565236625
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | cut -f2- -d:
```

does what you need.

It processes each line of the input and extracts all the fields (`-f`) starting with the second field up to the end of the line (`2-`), using `:` as delimiter (`-d`).

Read more about [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut).

Comment: `cut -f2- -d: file` also works, without a useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Not much to say. Using colon as field separator we only have 2 columns to work on.
Start first to remove the leading zero by sub and afterwards print second column.

```
awk -F: '{sub(/^0/,"",$2);print $2}' file

    5556808    0.916496542
    8883127    0.891518088
    10537079    0.827900035
    12497728    0.90517593
    13195463    NA
    22240159    0.809459655
    27050343    NA
    5556808    0.816581048
    8883127    0.864387435
    10537079    0.565236625
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

No need to perform any sub to remove the leading zeroes. We can use regular expression as awk field separator.

```
awk -F":(0+)?" '{print $2;}' <filename>
```